# How to change the color of selected row in ag grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-angular

I need to change the  selection color from blue(default color) to red bordered blue color in ag-grid.[image]

Refer the pic the blue color should be converted to thick blue with red border

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following to your css

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-row-selected {
    background-color: #4abbff;
}

.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-cell-focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: .ag-theme-balham .ag-row-selected {
    background-color: #4abbff;
}

.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-row-focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

Indtead of Cell I need Row. It works